# Is Google Play Developer API provide any user identity data when click reSubscribe button in Play Store?

Tags: android, subscription

I try to develop subscription function in my app recently and the project also got a back-end server.

Now I faced a question when **first subscription already ended** and then try to **click the reSubscribe button in Google Play Store**.

After searching many documents, I know there's got a parameter '**linkedPurchaseToken**' that google says it would send to our back-end server through **Real-time developer notifications**.
(https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/implementing-linkedpurchasetoken-correctly-to-prevent-duplicate-subscriptions-82dfbf7167da#eb81)
But the parameter only show up when old subscription not really finished(canceled but still in subscribe periods, upgrade, downgrade...etc).

How can I recognize brand new reSubscribe purchase without linkedPurchaseToken?
Is there any user identity data that I missed??

---

Or there has another method that App side can handle the resubscribe?
But I also call queryPurchase method to recongize the reSubscribe purchase, and I didn't see any parameters that tell me the purchase type.

**queryPurchase data**
Purchase. Json: {
"orderId":"GPA.3344-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX
packageName":"net",
"productId":"net.XXXXX.XXX.XXX.cs.XXX100",
"purchaseTime":1611111184135,
"purchaseState":0,
"purchaseToken":"token...",
"autoRenewing":true,
"acknowledged":true}

Thanks for any help and advise.

Comment: I think this question is better asked to Google Play Developer support as the behaviour you are wondering about is probably subject to change.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just think why iOS subscribe can identify the user, but android are not...